# Flask-Principal Best Practice of Handling PermissionDenied Exception

Tags: python, flask, flask-principal

I am new in writing flask and currently use `flask-principal` as my authorization mechanism.
When a user tries to access a url without the required permission, flask-principal raises a `PermissionDenied` Exception.

It causes my system to throw a `500 internal server` error.

How could I catch the specific exception and redirect user to a warning page instead?
If you could share a code example, that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can tell Flask-Principal that you want to raise a specific HTTP error code instead:

```
@app.route('/admin')
@admin_permission.require(http_exception=403)
def admin(request):
    # ...
```

Now [`flask.abort()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.abort) will be called instead of raising `PermissionDenied`. For the 403 error code you can then register an [error handler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers):

```
@app.errorhandler(403)
def page_not_found(e):
    session['redirected_from'] = request.url
    return redirect(url_for('users.login'))
```

where `url_for('users.login')` would return the route URL for a login page.